# use vue.js in django admin

Tags: vue.js, django-templates, django-admin

I want to use Django admin but I want to change some pages or change some elements in some pages. I want to use vue.js for this work. I don't have enough time to change all templates. how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Django docs has a page on [overriding the admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates) from there it's as easy as to add vue.js in a script tag and do all your vue stuff in that template. Just be aware that both Django and Vue uses `{{variable}}` syntax for variables.
The best here is to change vue's syntax.

ex:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: data,
    delimiters: ["<%","%>"]
});
```

Comment: one more point is using VueJS CDN way, so you basically just writing like normal javascript in html